# defineAttributes and rules

Tags: plugin-development, validation

[Using this fantastic article on validation,](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-5-custom-validators) I have written a custom validator class. Everything is working, but I'm curious about the `rules` and `defineAttributes` method(s). Most likely I'm just misunderstanding how it all works.

**MyModel.php**

```
    public function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'firstName' => array(
                'type' => AttributeType::Name,
                'required' => true
            ),
            'lastName' => array(
                'type' => AttributeType::Name,
                'required' => true
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'type' => AttributeType::Email,
                'required' => true
            ),
            'phone' => array(
                'type' => AttributeType::ClassName,
                'maxLength' => 14
            )
        );
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules[] = ['email', 'Craft\MyPlugin_EmailValidator'];

        return $rules;
    }
```

Do I really need both? I (thought) that `defineAttributes` was the `rules` method. Everything is working properly; I'm doing a check to make sure the email is unique. I have a unique key defined on the record as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both because there is no way to define custom validation rules from `defineAttributes()`.

Ultimately things like `'maxLength' => 14` in `defineAttributes()` automagically get normalized down to the `$rules` array that gets returned from the `rules` method, so you're just appending your custom rule onto that when you call:

```
$rules = parent::rules();
$rules[] = ['email', 'Craft\MyPlugin_EmailValidator'];
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I was more curious if I was re-inventing the wheel by including the `rules` call in addition to the `defineAttributes` method.  Thank you!