# More extensive documentation for defining models for plugins

Tags: plugin-development, models

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to define new models in plugins, but the documentation at http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/models doesn't get me very far.

For example, there is:

```
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'name' => AttributeType::String,
        'type' => array(AttributeType::Enum, 'values' => "alcohol,mixer,other"),
    );
}`
```

I've seen other plugins define attributes with an array element of `'required' => true`, but the only example I see here is `'values'`. Is there somewhere I can see a list of the available options when defining attributes? Or is it a better practice to define the attributes simply and then define validation rules in the `rules()` method?

I know the docs say to check out the CModel documentation, but it doesn't even have defineAttributes. Does Craft itself have more in depth documentation on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Stephen Lewis' [archived blog article](https://github.com/manifestuk/2016-10-blog-archive/blob/master/posts/2014-07-29--the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-1-foundations.yml) about validation. Even better, [buy the book](https://leanpub.com/craft-validation).

Comment: Also [this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/defineattributes-and-rules)